# JObject structure - How to iterate?

Tags: c#, json, loops

I hope someone can help me out even though this have properly been answered before i just cant seem to find the answer to this particular. My problem is i don't know how to get the values in the "value section" with `c#` code

```
{{
  "error": false,
  "value": [
    {
      "uploadid": "valuevaluevalue",
      "parentid": "othervalue",
      "id": "idvalue",
      "filename": "account.xml",
      "displayname": "account.xml",
      "size": 116,
      "md5": ""
    }
  ]
}}
```

I tried to use foreach but im confused when the key/value properties are available and what is a child and what is an array.

I've also tried with the jobject.GetValue("Id") but that gets me an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." . I believe its because that element is only in the second set, but i dont know how to "start there".

Comment: "that gets me an error" doesn't tell us what the error is...

Comment: It doesn't help that that isn't valid JSON to start with, due to the double braces.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated with the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Well it sounds like that's something you'd get after trying to *use* that value... and you haven't shown that. (It's always worth including a [mcve]...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing to do is understand your structure. It's somewhat odd, because `value` is actually an array, containing a single object. You should work out what you would want to do if you ever had *multiple* objects there.

Here's an example which dumps the values from each item of the array. This works after changing the `{{ ... }}` in your JSON to `{ ... }`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        var valueArray = (JArray) obj["value"];
        // Note: if the array contains non-objects,
        // this will fail
        foreach (JObject value in valueArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Values:");
            foreach (var property in value.Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Values:
  uploadid: valuevaluevalue
  parentid: othervalue
  id: idvalue
  filename: account.xml
  displayname: account.xml
  size: 116
  md5:
```

To get just the ID, you could use `value["id"]`.

Comment: Jon - Thank you! this works perfect. Did not even had to remove the extra braces

Comment: @Andreas: Hmm - that may be Json.NET being somewhat lenient. What you've shown *isn't* valid JSON. (The version of Json.NET I tried with gave an error of "Invalid property identifier character '{'" which seems reasonable to me...)

Comment: Alright thanks for pointing that out - i'll get rid of them for safety sake. Thanks again